# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: mCanvas.drawBitmap(...)

Tags: java, android, bitmap, outofmemoryerror

Есть следующий фотографирующий код:

```
Parameters mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
mParameters.setPictureSize(480, 360);
mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
mCamera.startPreview();
Thread.sleep(3000L);
final ByteArrayOutputStream i1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] i2, Camera i3) {
        try {
            i1.write(i2);
            i1.flush();
            i1.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }
    }

});
```

И есть код, рисующий на полученной фотографии:

```
Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 360, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(i1.toByteArray(), 0, i1.toByteArray().length), 0, 0, mPaint);
mPaint.setColor(Color.argb(128, 0, 0, 0));
mCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, 290, 34, mPaint);
mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
mPaint.setTextSize(24);
String description = "2016.21.10 17:25:30"
mCanvas.drawText(description, 8, 26, mPaint);
...
mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mOutputStream);
mOutputStream.flush();
mBitmap.recycle();
```

Но вылетает `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
>
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:443)
>
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:460)
>
> at mypackage.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:134)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

которую я получил при помощи блока `try {...} catch (Error e1) {...}`. В 134-ой строке записано это:

```
mCanvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(i1.toByteArray(), 0, i1.toByteArray().length), 0, 0, mPaint);
```

Как исправить ошибку? Может быть у меня что-то не так с кодом? Дело в том, что я пробовал это сделать на нескольких телефонах, и, на одном из них приложение вылетало сразу при попытке нарисовать надпись, а на других двоих вылетало только на третьей фотографии. Я также пробовал сделать и немного по-другому:

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(i1.toByteArray(), 0, i1.toByteArray().length).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
...
```

то есть скопировать полученный `Bitmap`, который будет `mutable = true`. И флаг `Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` я тоже пробовал убрать. Ничего из этого не помогло, ошибка всё та же.

Comment: у тебя же память заканчивается

Comment: mCanvas.drawBitmap слишком много памяти просит. ему не хватает и крэшится приложение. 
`i1` не слишком много памяти занимает ?

Comment: В смысле `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Сомневаюсь. Сейчас попробую как-нибудь его заменить на `byte[]`.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, нет. Проверил только что. Я знаю, что много памяти требуется. Но неужели надо больше чем 1 ГБ?

Comment: где то точно течет, и скорее всего  там

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, допустим. Как быть?? Уже неделю потратил на это.. много примеров пересмотрел, статей, полезного практически ничего не нашёл в этом направлении

Comment: для начала нужно посмотреть какой объект сколько жрет, это можно сделать с помощью `java agent` . выполните и приложите скрин к вопросу